# RDBMS and KAFKA CONNECTION

Tags: apache-kafka

Can someone help me with the steps to integrate Kafka with RDBMS, I have to stream data from a table into HBase.In my cluster kafka and zookeeper already installed.**In this case which one is better either Github's confluent or striim?**  Any solution other than Kafka will also help.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Which RDBMS? Striim has support for MySQL, Oracle, and MSSQL out of the box. We have a special download for confluent users as well:

http://www.striim.com/download-striim-for-confluent/